# error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I get the below error when trying to build my Flutter APP for iOS using Codemagic. I have set the signing to automatic and given all the credentials required as mentioned in this [medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-sign-flutter-apps-for-ios-automatically-without-a-mac-a2dc9cfa5a6c)

```
❌  error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Can someone please let me know where to set the development team. **I am building this on a Windows machine with dev editor as VS code**.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and hope my solution will resolve yours.

**It should be noted that the "Runner" Xcode project in the screenshot can be found in <your_flutter_project>/ios/ folder. Open the Runner.xcodeproj file in XCode.**

**1. Go the Project Navigator.**
**2. Go the Signing & Capabilities tab.**
**3. Add a team and try to build the app again.**

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: also see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 15):

If you already set an account but still give a signing error try to switch between Debug and Release. Follow the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Its best to use xcode for ios development, but there is a possible workaround . There is a file ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, where you could add the following lines in order to add a development team
``

```
diff --git a/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
index 16710ed..2ea1638 100644
--- a/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
+++ b/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -157,6 +156,7 @@
                                TargetAttributes = {
                                        97C146ED1CF9000F007C117D = {
                                                CreatedOnToolsVersion = 7.3.1;
+                                               DevelopmentTeam = BCG58GM5FG;
                                        };
                                };
                        };
@@ -437,6 +438,7 @@
                        buildSettings = {
                                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                                CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";
+                               DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = BCG58GM5FG;
                                ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;
                                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                                        "$(inherited)",
@@ -460,6 +462,7 @@
                        buildSettings = {
                                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                                CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";
+                               DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = BCG58GM5FG;
                                ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;
                                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                                        "$(inherited)",
```

The positioning of the lines is not important, but should be in that order.

Comment: after a week of trying to get things working, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: note: i withheld making the first change inside `TargetAttributes` because codemagic reverted to 'manual' codesigning with it set

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting a Team **for All your build types** (normally bundle identifier and Team will be the same in all your build types -Debug, Release and Profile-). To do so, select the All tab at `Signing & Capabilities` and set there your Team and your Bundle Identifier. Also, I'd recommend you check the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox. Doing so was the way it solved the error it in my case.

[image]